# How can I make below code to show grouping by country ranks in same div, example if in second loop rank 2nd must be show in same 2nd class div

Tags: php

```php
foreach ($get_data as $dataa) {
    $countries_0 = '';
    $countries_1 = '';
    $countries_2 = '';
    $countries_3 = '';
    $countries_4 = '';
    $countries_5 = '';

    if ($dataa->country_name == "United Arab Emirates") {
        $country_name = 'UAE';
    } else {
        $country_name = $dataa->country_name;
    }

    if ($dataa->total == 0) {
        $countries_0 = '0'. $country_name;
    } else if ($dataa->total == 1) {
        $countries_1 = '1'. $country_name;
    } else if ($dataa->total == 2) {
        $countries_2 = '2'. $country_name;
    } else if ($dataa->total == 3) {
        $countries_3 = '3'. $country_name;
    } else if ($dataa->total == 4) {
        $countries_4 = '4'. $country_name;
    } else if ($dataa->total == 5) {
        $countries_5 = '5'. $country_name;
    } else {
        $countries_0 = $country_name;
    }

    if (!empty($countries_0)) {
        sort($countries_0);
        echo   '<div class="zero"><div>';
        echo $countries_0;
    }
    if (!empty($countries_1)) {
        sort($countries_1);
        echo '<div class="one">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo $countries_1;

        echo  '</div></div>';
        ;
    }
    if (!empty($countries_2)) {
        ksort($countries_2);
        echo '<div class="two">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo $countries_2;

        echo  '</div></div>';
        ;
    }
    if (!empty($countries_3)) {
        ksort($countries_3);
        echo '<div class="three">';
        echo '<div>';

        echo  '</div></div>';

    }
    if (!empty($countries_4)) {
        echo '<div class="four">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo $countries_4;
        echo  '</div></div>';
    }
    if (!empty($countries_5)) {
        ksort($countries_5);
        echo '<div class="five">';
        echo '<div>';
        echo $countries_5;
        echo  '</div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit an example of the ranking you want into the question? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. What does a $dataa record look like?

Comment: (You've also tagged this as wordpress.com-hosting, which I guess is wrong, unless this code is for a WordPress VIP site? And otherwise I'm not sure this is a WordPress-specific question, and might be better asked on StackOverflow.)

Comment: Hi Rup, Thank you for your response. I want each loop not to repeat <div class="one"> div it shows only once next time if it has a value shown in the same div which generate in the first loop. I want to make a grouping of the same countries' numbers